# How to send a large file to post request in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to send a file in post request. My code is:

```
import requests
data = {"username": user,
        "password": password,}

files = {'media': open(file_path, 'rb')}


r = requests.post(url, data=data, files = files)
```

It works fine with small files. But if I try to upload a large file (*.avi > 1gb for example), I get a MemoryError. What should I do?

Comment: I would try [streaming the file into chunks](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads)

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the definition of `_encode_files` in requests/models.py you will see that the read method is called on the file to read the entire file into memory unconditionally.
As a result, the file must fit into memory.
The actual limit will depend on your available virtual memory.  On a 64-bit system you can make this quite large by allocating swap or a pagefile.
You can almost certainly use a module like `aiohttp` and your own encoding of files (or a `PUT` method) to send larger files